# Unable to locate element error in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Html:

```
<a class="pointer" ng-click="openLogin()">Log In</a>
```

My code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Log In")));
        WebElement logIN = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In"));
        logIN.click();
```

Error I'm getting:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link
>   text","selector":"Log In"}   (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.116)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stack

Comment: html code :<a class="pointer" ng-click="openLogin()">Log In</a>

Answer (score 0):

CHeck if this works

```
//*[@ng-click='pointer']
```